# How can I see if I have any ether?

Tags: ether

I am using geth and ethminer on Windows.

Looking at geth, I can see that it is up to date because it is very slowing showing that it is importing new chain segment.  I think that means that geth is caught up and it is only adding new transactions as they come.

I am using ethminer to mine and so I think that geth is fairly busy with the mining.

I also have a Ethereum wallet, pointing to the same exact path that geth is using (C:\Users\frank\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum Wallet\binaries\Geth\unpacked) and using geth I made 100% sure that it is using the same ethereum account as the wallet.

As a matter of fact, when I open the wallet and geth is running, the wallet shows that it is not using geth.  So, I think that somehow the wallet figured out that geth was already running and connects to it, rather than trying to run another instance.

My question is, why does the wallet always says that it is syncing and it has downloaded 2 million of 4+ million blocks?  The wallet always appear to be stuck around the same number, although geth appears to be up-to-date.

so, my question, if geth is busy mining and the wallet does not work, how else can I check if I have any ether?  Can geth mine while it is in console mode?  Can I access some web interface to see my wallet status?

Thanks!

Comment: You can check on [Etherscan](https://etherscan.io/) all the information about your account.

Comment: Etherscan is beautiful!  Better than I could have hoped for

Comment: Happy I could help I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check on [Etherscan](https://etherscan.io/) all the information about your account.

You could also import your account to a different wallet like [Metamask](https://metamask.io/) that doesn't require you to run a full node, which will allow you to do transactions and more.

Or you can just wait for your wallet to finish syncing.